# Animating Change in NSPopover’s contentViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, nspopover

I have an `NSPopover`, which switches between two View Controllers.

I set one at launch,

```
self.popover.contentViewController = viewController1;
```

and I change to the other one based on a user action:

```
self.popover.contentViewController = viewController2;
```

AppKit does some animations to the `NSPopover` itself to accomodate the second VC, which work well, but the transition between the two View Controller’s views is jarring. I would like them to slide in and out horizontally or at the very least cross fade.

I am using layer-backed views, which I'm setting like this in the `AppDelegate`’s `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method:

```
self.popover.contentViewController.view.wantsLayer = YES;
self.popover.contentViewController.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;
```

Here’s what I’ve tried:

- fading out the first View Controller's view in `-viewWillDisappear` and fading in the second View Controller's view in `-viewWillAppear`. This fades out the first VC’s view immediately and does not fade the second VC’s view back in
- fading out the first VC’s view’s layer before switching the popover’s `contentViewController`:

  ```
  CALayer *theLayer = self.popover.contentViewController.view.layer;

  CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
  fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
  fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
  fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
  [theLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];

  theLayer.opacity = 0.0;

  self.popover.contentViewController = self.viewController;
  ```

This second strategy doesn't wait for the animation to finish before switching the View Controllers over.

How do I animate changing the NSPopover’s `contentViewController`?

Answer (score -1):

So since you have multiple child view controllers in a parent view controller you should follow the view controller containment protocol. Rather than animating the views you want to animate the transition between the view controllers themselves.

```
toController.view.frame = fromController.view.bounds;                           
[containerViewController addChildViewController:toController];                                     
[fromController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[containerViewController transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                                     toViewController:toViewController
                                             duration:0.2
                                              options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                           animations:nil
                                           completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                               [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                               [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:containerViewController];
                                               toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds;
                                           }];
```

Where containerViewController is your contentViewController.

Pretty much just tell the old view controller it's being removed from the parent, animate the transition, and remove the old controller and let the new controller know it's been moved to the parent.

More info from apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

And good tutorial on custom transitions here: http://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/

Comment: Thanks, Max. This question is about Cocoa (Mac), not Cocoa touch (iOS), so while the methods are similar, they're not the same. I did end up using an equivalent to the method you suggested.

Comment: I should also note that I could not do this directly with the NSPopover’s `contentViewController`, I had to add a dummy empty View Controller to act as the "parent" of my two VCs and assign NSPopover's `contentViewController` to that parent View Controller.